# Jquery variables not clearing values properley on vertical scrolling list

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, scroll

I have a list of addresses which is picked up when someone enters their postcode and distance from postcode in miles.

The list which is brought back is displayed in a vertical scrolling list using the following code:

```
  $(".upHide").hide();
   // get the number of .child elements
   var totalitems;
   var currentscrollval;

   totalitems = $(".addressscroll .storeLi").length;
   if (totalitems >= 2) {
       $(".downHide").show();
   }
   // get the height of .w6392597
   var scrollval = $('.storeLi').height();
   // work out the total height.
   var totalheight = (totalitems * scrollval) - ($(".addressscroll").height());
   $(document).on("click", ".downHide", function () {
       currentscrollval = $('.addressscroll').scrollTop();

       alert("totalitems " + totalitems);
       alert("scrollval " + scrollval);
       alert("currentscrollval " + currentscrollval);
       alert("totalheight " + totalheight);

       $('.addressscroll').scrollTop(scrollval + currentscrollval);

       // hide/show buttons
       if (currentscrollval == totalheight) {
           $(this).hide();
       }
       else {
           $(".upHide").show();

       }
   }); $(document).on("click", ".upHide", function () {
       var currentscrollval = parseInt($('.addressscroll').scrollTop());

       $('.addressscroll').scrollTop(currentscrollval - scrollval);

       // hide/show buttons
       if ((scrollval + currentscrollval) == scrollval) {
           $(this).hide();
       }
       else {
           $(".downHide").show();
       }
   });
```

With the html:

```
 <div class="divAddress" style="display: block;">
        <div id="up">
            <img class="upHide" alt="top" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/moreup.png" style="display: inline;">
        </div>
        <div class="addressscroll">
            <ul id="locatorScroll">
                <li class="storeLi">
                    <div class="singleadddress">
                        <p class="storeNameP">1 Hi Spek</p>
                        <p class="storeP">
                        <p class="linksP">
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <li class="storeLi">
                    <div class="singleadddress">
                        <p class="storeNameP">2 A L Young</p>
                        <p class="storeP">
                        <p class="linksP">
                    </div>
                </li>

                ..MORE LIST ITEMS HERE
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="down">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this all works well.

However if I scroll down the list and then change the distance in miles a new list is brought back (I am using  AJAN and JSON to retrieve the list) but totalItems and CurrentScrollVal seem to be holding the values.  So where I have put the alerts when it is the first time round the alertsz are showing the following (clicked 6 times):

totalItems   8  8   8   8   8   8

scrollval    130    130 130 130 130 130

currentscrollval 130    260 390 520 650 778

totalheight  778    778 778 778 778 778

but on the second time round the list is not shown in order - so it may be half way down the list and the alerts will show (when clicked once):

totalItems   8
scrollval    130
currentscrollval 130
totalheight  778
totalItems   31
scrollval    130
currentscrollval 350
totalheight  3768

so it will gop through the alerts twice first of all put the values from teh first list and then put the valus from the second list that has been brought back.

The effect this has is that the list does not start at the top and it seems to miss items in the list so even though I can see the 3rd list item when I inspect element when I scroll its not there.

**Edit** more detail on the full code:

```
 <div class="maps">
                        <div class="divOuter">
                            <div class="divLocator">
                                <div class="topSection">
                                    <div class="topSectionLeft">
                                        <p class="storeP">
                                            Please enter your Postcode &nbsp;
                                            <input id="enterPostCode" type="text" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="topSectionRight">
                                        <p class="storeP">
                                            Distance from your location &nbsp;
                                            <select id="distanceMiles" name="distanceMilesChange">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="5">5 miles</option>
                                                <option value="10">10 miles</option>
                                                <option value="15">15 miles</option>
                                                <option value="20">20 miles</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <input id="enterMiles" type="hidden" /></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="hiddenPostMsg">
                                        Please enter your postcode and then select a distance</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="upgradeTab">
                                </div>
                                <div class="divMapsArea">
                                    <div class="googleMaps">
                                        <!-- Displays the Google Map which was defined in the initialize script above, and defines the map size on the screen -->
                                        <div id="gmap_canvas">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divAddress">
                                        <div id="up">
                                            <img class="upHide" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/moreup.png"
                                                alt="top" /></div>
                                        <div class="addressscroll">
                                            <ul id="locatorScroll">
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="down">
                                            <img class="downHide" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/moredown.png"
                                                alt="top" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="loading" style="display: none">
                                        <img src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/ajax_loader_large.gif" alt="Loader" /><p>
                                            Loading...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHqhrDdmkEFuDv55BeCK7nFkfYGdYSW20&sensor=false">
                        </script>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
               //<![CDATA[
                           //if the postcode input field is clicked on the dropdown should clear

                           $("#enterPostCode").click(function () {
                               $("#distanceMiles").find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');

                           });

                           $("#hiddenPostMsg ").hide();

                           $(".divAddress").hide();

                           var map;
                           //set up the markers array so that we can clear them
                           var markers = [];

                           // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
                           function clearMarkers() {
                               for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                                   markers[i].setMap(null);
                               }
                               markers.length = 0;
                           };

                           function initialize() {

                               var zoomGrade = 10;

                               //create the google map
                               var mapProp = {
                                   center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.694031, 0.04505),
                                   zoom: zoomGrade,
                                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                               };
                               map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), mapProp);

                               //for some reason .change was firing twice and with the unbind it meant it only fired once
                               $('#distanceMiles').unbind();

                               $("#distanceMiles").change(function () {

                                   //clear the old markers if there are any
                                   clearMarkers();

                                   $(".divAddress").hide();
                                   $(".addressscroll ul").html('');

                                   $("#distanceMiles option:selected").each(function () {

                                       var manufacturerId = 109;

                                       var postcodeEntered = $("#enterPostCode").val();

                                       var milesEntered = $(this).val();

                                       if (postcodeEntered != "" && milesEntered != "") {

                                           $("#hiddenPostMsg ").hide();

                                           var theUrl = "/Widgets/GetPostcodes/" + manufacturerId + "/" + postcodeEntered + "/" + milesEntered;
                                           $.ajax({
                                               type: "POST",
                                               //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                               url: theUrl,
                                               data: { 'manufacturerId': manufacturerId, 'postcodeEntered': postcodeEntered, 'milesEntered': milesEntered },
                                               dataType: "json",
                                               success: function (data) {

                                                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                                       var item = data[i];

                                                       //the count goes next to the retailer so we know which marker is for which
                                                       var count = i + 1;

                                                       //to custom the markers i need to use the number we are on (i)
                                                       var iconurl = "https://where-to-buy.co/content/images/marker" + count + ".png";

                                                       //Sets the initial map location (latitude, longitude) in decimal degree format, and the zoom level (1 is zoomed out - 21 is farthest zoom in)
                                                       map.setZoom(item.ZoomLevel);
                                                       map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(item.OriginalLat, item.OriginalLong));

                                                       //Close bracket to end the function named initialize !!!very important to not delete this!!!
                                                       //javascript that sets up variables that enable the map to draw a custom icon.
                                                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                           position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.StoreLat, item.StoreLong),
                                                           icon: iconurl,
                                                           map: map
                                                       });
                                                       marker.setMap(map);
                                                       //put into an array so that they clear
                                                       markers.push(marker);
                                                       //End of add marker code
                                                       var showDistance = item.Distance.toFixed(2);
                                                       //now i need to create a list that will display on the right hand side inside .addressscroll
                                                       $(".addressscroll ul").append("<li class =\"storeLi\"><div class=singleadddress><p class=\"storeNameP\">" + count + " " + item.StoreName + "</p><p class=\"storeP\">" + item.Address1 + "<br/>" + item.TownCity + " " + item.Postcode + "<br/>" + item.Telephone + "<br/>" + showDistance + " miles</p><p class =\"linksP\" ><a class =\"storeA\" href = \"https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + item.MapsPostcode + "\" target=\"_blank\" >Display Map | </a><a class =\"storeA\" href = \"https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=" + item.OriginalMapsPostcode + "&daddr=" + item.MapsPostcode + "\" target=\"_blank\" >Display Route</a></p></div></li> ");

                                                       //Creates a directions object and registers a map and DIV to hold the resulting computed directions
                                                       //                                                var directionsPanel;
                                                       //                                                var directions;
                                                       //                                                directionsPanel = document.getElementById("my_directions_div");
                                                       //                                                directions = new GDirections(gmap, directionsPanel);
                                                       //                                                //Specify the FROM and TO for your directions: postcode to postcode
                                                       //                                                directions.load("from: "+ item.OriginalPostcode +", to: "+ item.Postcode + "");

                                                   }

                                                   $(".divAddress").show();

                                                   $(".upHide").hide();
                                                   // get the number of .child elements
                                                   var totalitems;
                                                   var currentscrollval;

                                                   totalitems = $(".addressscroll .storeLi").length;
                                                   if (totalitems >= 2) {
                                                       $(".downHide").show();
                                                   }
                                                   // get the height of .w6392597
                                                   var scrollval = $('.storeLi').height();
                                                   // work out the total height.
                                                   var totalheight = (totalitems * scrollval) - ($(".addressscroll").height());
                                                   $(document).on("click", ".downHide", function () {
                                                       currentscrollval = $('.addressscroll').scrollTop();

//                                                       alert("totalitems " + totalitems);
//                                                       alert("scrollval " + scrollval);
//                                                       alert("currentscrollval " + currentscrollval);
//                                                       alert("totalheight " + totalheight);

                                                       $('.addressscroll').scrollTop(scrollval + currentscrollval);

                                                       // hide/show buttons
                                                       if (currentscrollval == totalheight) {
                                                           $(this).hide();
                                                       }
                                                       else {
                                                           $(".upHide").show();

                                                       }
                                                   }); $(document).on("click", ".upHide", function () {
                                                       var currentscrollval = parseInt($('.addressscroll').scrollTop());

                                                       $('.addressscroll').scrollTop(currentscrollval - scrollval);

                                                       // hide/show buttons
                                                       if ((scrollval + currentscrollval) == scrollval) {
                                                           $(this).hide();
                                                       }
                                                       else {
                                                           $(".downHide").show();
                                                       }
                                                   });

                                                   if (totalitems == 0) {
                                                       $(".downHide").hide();
                                                       $("#hiddenPostMsg ").show();
                                                       $("#hiddenPostMsg ").text("Invalid Postcode. Please try again");
                                                   }

                                               }

                                           });

                                       }
                                       else if (postcodeEntered == "") {

                                           //here i want to clear the dropdown aswel
                                           $("#hiddenPostMsg ").show();
                                           $("#hiddenPostMsg ").text("Please enter your postcode and then select a distance");
                                           $("#distanceMiles").find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');

                                       }

                                   });

                               });

                           }
                           google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                           google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        </script>
                        <!-- Signals to the browser that a section of javascript follows, and to read accordingly -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
               //<![CDATA[
                            // Bind my loading div to the ajax send and complete functions
                            $().ready(function () {
                                $("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function () {
                                    $(this).show();
                                }).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {
                                    $(this).hide();
                                });
                            });
        //]]>
                        </script>
                        <!-- Signals to the browser that a section of javascript follows, and to read accordingly -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
               //<![CDATA[
                            // Bind my loading div to the ajax send and complete functions
                            $().ready(function () {
                                $("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function () {
                                    $(this).show();
                                }).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {
                                    $(this).hide();
                                });
                            });

        //]]>
                        </script>
                        <!-- Signals to the browser that a section of javascript follows, and to read accordingly -->
                        <%--  <%= Html.GoogleMapsScriptsReturnPostcodeData(Model)%>--%>
                    </div>
```

What this page is doing is: A user enters a postcode and selects a distance in miles from a drop down list - when the user selects the distance the jquery kicks in and sends information through AJAX to the controller (MVC3) to bring back in a JSON object a list of addresses that are the certain distance from the post code.

This all works fine until the user has scrolled down the list and then selects a new distance from the drop down list - when this happens the list of addresses is not being displayed propeleya nd this is when I am getting the isssue that I explained about above (I hope this makes more sense)

**Edit 2**

What I really want to do is make sure that on this call:

```
 $("#distanceMiles").change(function () {
```

No previous values are left behind - especially for totalItems and currentscrollval

**Edit 3**

Right I think i was looking at the part of code I think it is because I am appending code rather than replacing it:

```
 $(".addressscroll ul").replace("<li class =\"storeLi\"><div class=singleadddress><p class=\"storeNameP\">" + count + " " + item.StoreName + "</p><p class=\"storeP\">" + item.Address1 + "<br/>" + item.TownCity + " " + item.Postcode + "<br/>" + item.Telephone + "<br/>" + showDistance + " miles</p><p class =\"linksP\" ><a class =\"storeA\" href = \"https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + item.MapsPostcode + "\" target=\"_blank\" >Display Map | </a><a class =\"storeA\" href = \"https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=" + item.OriginalMapsPostcode + "&daddr=" + item.MapsPostcode + "\" target=\"_blank\" >Display Route</a></p></div></li> ");
```

So just need to figure out how to check if it exists if it doesn't I need to append if it does exist i need to replace.

**Edit 4**

Actually not sure if that was the issue as I have added

```
  $("#distanceMiles").change(function () {

                                   //I want to remove the list if there is one
                                   //check if storeLi exist if it does replace if not append
                                  if ($(".storeLi").length > 0) {

                                       $(".addressscroll ul").empty();
                                   }
```

and even though this empties the ul so only new ones are appended it still doesn t work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How and when does the above code get called and which part of the jQuery updates the list (I don't think you have included that bit in the code above)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: i ll edit the question with a bit more detail

Comment: reproducing the issue in a fiddle would help greatly as well. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm afraid i can t really show it in fiddler as to return the list it is using mvc3 ajax - json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that because addressscroll height was being remembered it was making the list position wrong and therefore hiding some of the list items.  To overcome this I made sure that adressscroll was set back to 0 by doing the following after the   $("#distanceMiles").change as follows:

```
 $(".addressscroll").scrollTop(0);
```

Which reset it so that the list always came back as it should